# How can one fix the Pesky windows of "Windows installer" which pops up every time

Tags: microsoft-office

I have Microsoft Office 2003 Professonal edition on WinXP. Everytime i double click either of below files(MS office related) to open it: *.xls, *.ppt, *.pps, or try to open MS Outlook, This Windows Installer window opens up and tries to look for one package/file named - PRO11.MSI.

And it says since the path is on a networked resource, it cannot find it. After this when i cancel thatw window, the original file is not opened, just the application is opened. Then i have to again double click the *.ppt, *.xls file i want to open, and now it opens.

Is there any problem here in my MS Office installation? What is it?

How can i fix this popup from being opened everytime?

Thank you.
-AD

Comment: Should this go to superuser?

Comment: Probably should, but until it's out of private beta we can probably assume it relates to a corporate deployment gone wrong. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have "install on first use" or "run from the network" selected for some of the Office components (my guess would be clip gallery, syriac font, additional themes or something like that) which is triggering the installer.  Rerunning Office setup and selecting "run all from my computer" will fix it.

Comment: Please note you will need the installation media to re-run the install

Comment: Quite correct, my bad for omitting it.