# Domain migration results in MS Office running installer every time

Tags: windows-xp, migration, microsoft-office, windows-installer

My workplace is migrating multiple departments, each with their own AD domain into one combined one. For the most part this is all ok, however we've run into a problem with MS Office 2003 installs on Windows XP (perhaps would affect users on Windows 7 with Office 2010, but yet to try them).

After migrating users, when they try and open any MS Office files, they get a Windows Installer running saying that "the feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable" and to point it to another network location. The server that it *was* on is of course now gone...

The first thing we tried was to update from Office 2003 to Office 2010 which was available over the network in Add/Remove Programs. For any other users of the machine aside from the migrated user, this worked fine, but the migrated user still got the same installer prompt when opening existing files even though Office had upgraded. Launching directly was all ok.

I've done some searching and came across this previous question: [How can one fix the Pesky windows of "Windows installer" which pops up every time](https://serverfault.com/questions/48503/how-can-one-fix-the-pesky-windows-of-windows-installer-which-pops-up-every-tim) which indicates that install on first use or run from network is the problem.

My question is, how can I get around this? Any way to disable this and configure to run all from my computer *before* the migration takes place? I never saw options to run all from my computer during the network install of Office 2010 and would have expected that this, coming from a new network location, would have resolved it.

Any help or ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found *a* solution to this, so answering it in case anyone else ever has this issue.

Uninstalling Office 2003 whilst logged on as user, before migration, worked fine. This enabled migration to go ahead seemingly without the user having any Office settings files or registry entries in their profile. After migration, a re-install on user's new profile ran through all ok.